# Android adb command to simulate the touch event and Superuser apk suggestion

Tags: android, adb, root

while I request privilege permission for my app`.exec("su")`, my SuperSU app pops up to request me to press the "Grant" button to allow my app to obtain the root privilege. For some reasons, my screen is not big enough which makes me unable to press the "Grant" button comes with the SuperSU app. I assume that adb command sendevent might help me to complete this step but it's really difficult to guess the coordinate for pressing the button.

Is there any other way can do this or other alternative app can do it without pressing the Grant button?

Any clue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: that's a customized device which has a very small screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably customize the superuser app to relocate the button.

Or if you have a root shell on the device (via adb perhaps?), you could make a setuid copy toolbox sh eliminating the need for the button dialog, but that would leave it available to anything on the device, which is quite risky.

At any rate, it looks like you may also be misunderstanding what superuser is capable of doing: your app cannot run as root, it can only launch a helper process which does.

Somewhat better than any of these open-ended root access ideas would be to have a fixed function, statically linked setuid executable accepting no inputs which does whatever privileged task you wanted to have happen.  The shorter that program is the better your chances of auditing it.

Comment: Hi Chris,
Could you tell me how to implement it since for now I am just doing some experiments for my own rooted device.

"Or if you have a root shell on the device (via adb perhaps?), you could make a setuid copy toolbox sh eliminating the need for the button dialog, but that would leave it available to anything on the device, which is quite risky. "

Thank you.

Comment: If you are going to do something that serious to a device, I think it's better you first learn about what you are getting into by researching the concept of setuid executables yourself.  One thing I will mention however is that chmod on android requires an octal permission - it does not understand the symbolic permissions which can be used for convenience on lots of desktop unixes.

Comment: Thank you Chris. I will take your advice.